# AbstractMethodError when use java 8 default interface methods and implementation in different libs

Tags: java, android, android-studio, aar

[image: Common scheme]

I have an java interface with default method (`ITest`) and java implementation (`Test`) defined in 2 different libraries (`aar`).  In `app` module I create instance of the `Test` and call `Test.test()`. `AbstractMethodError` occurs at this moment.
**This happens only I use Java in the libraries (for Kotlin all ok) and build apk by `Build - Generate Signed APK`.
If application run with `Run` menu all work as expected.**

lib1 (with interface):

```
public interface ITest {
    default void test() {
    }
}
```

lib2 (with implementation):

```
public class Test implements ITest {
}
```

app:

```
private fun runTest() {
    try {
        Test().test()
        Log.d(TAG, "call success")
    } catch (e: AbstractMethodError) {
        Log.d(TAG, "call fail e = $e")
    }
}
```

libraries and application build.config support Java8:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

[Here is very simple demo project](https://github.com/crainzavr/PoC_AME_java_default_method)

How I must use Java default methods in my case?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: @NikhilJain Yes, The problem was the empty <dependencies> in the lib1 pom file. After I filled in the <dependencies>, everything worked fine.